# Git repo unpack-objects failed

Tags: git, filesystems, wsl-2

Lately, my git become corrupted when I run `git pull` I receive this:

```
~/projects/cp$ git pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 4, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 1), reused 4 (delta 1), pack-reused 0
error: object file .git/objects/45/b462ce55a7bac640c72a4b589c7fc6febd77dd is empty
fatal: loose object 45b462ce55a7bac640c72a4b589c7fc6febd77dd (stored in .git/objects/45/b462ce55a7bac640c72a4b589c7fc6febd77dd) is corrupt
fatal: unpack-objects failed
```

So I backed up the `.git` folder and deleted the empty object and run `git fsck --full`.

Now when I do `git pull` I receive this error:

```
~/projects/cp$ git pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 4, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 1), reused 4 (delta 1), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), 11.49 KiB | 11.49 MiB/s, done.
fatal: unresolved deltas left after unpacking
fatal: unpack-objects failed
```

- My code is in `WSL-2 Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS`,
- Running with `Docker Desktop 4.1.1 (69879)` [for speed I put the files in WSL]
- Git version `2.33.1`
- I'm using Intliji PHP Storm

I recloned to a new folder and there are no problems there. I'm trying to figure out what causes this and how to fix it.

I suspect it might be a filesystem level corruption

Comment: *I suspect it might be a filesystem level corruption* It is, although as "corruption" goes it's just the minor lack of any actual *data* in some file. (This isn't really "minor" at all, more of a , but at least your data haven't been replaced with other data, which would potentially be even worse.)

Answer (score 0):

Found this [issue on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5026) and [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/kpj5oq/wsl2_corrupting_git_repositories_and_shell_history/) having the same problem, I guess this happen on windows shutdown, so the solution is to shutdown wsl manually with `wsl.exe --shutdown` and I will need to try to shutdown WSL myself, and I will report back if I have this problem again,